# How to copy stored procedure with new name?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, copy

For example, I have sp named like 'myStoredProcedure'. And I need to copy this stored procedure with 'myStoredProcedureNew' name in the same server. What is the best practice?

Comment: Just grab the script that created the first stored proc, adapt the name, and execute it again in SQL Server Mgmt Studio......

Comment: Is there way to make copy like rename syntax? EXEC sp_rename 'mystoredprocedure', 'mystoredprocedureNewName';

Answer (score 2):

One important question is, why are copying the procedure?

If it is because you have changed the logic and want to test it, then you really have a new version of the same procedure. The best approach in that case would be to get the script from source control, change the logic and test it. If it works, you can commit the code to source control and if not you simply revert to the previous version of the script.

If you want to make a second stored procedure using the first one as a starting point or template, then you will indeed have two separate procedures. Here you should get the first procedure from source control, edit it as required to change the procedure name and logic, save it in a separate script file and add the second script to source control. So you would have two scripts in source control, one for each procedure.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide some more information about why you need to copy the procedure.

**EDIT:** You explained that you want to do this for 100 procedures and you want to have both old and new procedures available in the database (I assume for backwards compatibility). That sounds like you want to have two different names for the same thing and in that case synonyms could be useful.

You can quickly create synonyms with the new name that reference the old procedures, so you can start using the new names in code. Then when (if?) you're ready to physically drop the old procedures, you can drop the synonyms and rename the  procedures. Whether or not this is a good alternative depends on how you plan to manage the transition from old to new procedure names, and how you manage DDL in source control.

If synonyms aren't useful in your case then you can always follow the steps in the second scenario I described. It should be easy to copy and edit the 100 files with a small script and of course as long as you are using source control then it's easy to undo mistakes.

Comment: It is long story. The main thing is that we have feature in our project and this feature was deployed with sp's name prefix '_matrix'. And now we doing refactoring - remove this prefix, but to be sure I need to have sp with old name. So, that is why I am looking for the best way do it.

Comment: @Yara are you needing this for a large number of stored procedures? ie A script that will find procs with the '_matrix' prefix and create new ones?

Comment: @Yara I updated my answer based on your additional information